# How to directly read value from Windows Service with VB6?

Tags: c#, windows, vb6, windows-services

How can I directly read a value from Windows Service with VB6?

I wrote a Windows Service with C# which generate a string and I want to read this value with VB6.

For example, Windows Service Application generate a string variable like this for each 10 second:

```
string id = "1422144";
```

after 10 second

```
string id = "2462778";
```

I want to read this values with VB6 each 10 second. I can read it from text file when I create and write this value to text with Windows Service but I don't want to create a text file. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no "Common" way to communicate with windows service. You a free to use whatever you like. Named pipes / WCF / even ASP.Net.

Comment: Would help to know how the service 'Generates' the string.  As @vasily.sib says, there are many ways to make this accessible to other programs/processes.  Seeing what your service looks like would help.

Comment: @GPW I'm just trying right now. It's like: string[] second = {DateTime.Now.Second.ToString()};
File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Users\slient\Desktop\note.txt", second);

Comment: Is this actually running as a Service?  not just an application that's updating this file all the time?

Comment: @GPW It's just updating file but it runs as windows service at background. I don't want to update file i just want to pass value to VB6 directly.

Comment: Basically it depends on what you're actually trying to do.  If all this service will ever do is create small strings, then maybe you could make it pump values onto a message queue of some sort which the client could watch (there are various technologies that do this sort of thing).  If this is going to form the basis of something more substantial then perhaps you could create a RESTful service instead, or even come up with your own TCP/IP based protocol... Every approach has advantages and disadvantages so it depends on what you're trying to achieve in the end with this

Comment: With the exceptions of debuggers, malware and anti-virus software, processes don't "directly" access other processes. There's always some form of IPC mechanism at play, whether that be the crude one already used here using the file system, slightly fancier tricks using memory mapped files, or full blown communication stacks. Without knowing more about the overall goal (really, the VB application gets the string and then does nothing with it?) it's difficult to know whether it's worth going fancier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use MSMQ (Message Queue) approach (note, I've not checked this exhaustively so it's just to get started):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973860.aspx

http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=131272&seqNum=6

To create self-hosted OWIN Web Api 2.0 service, I'd recommend using TopShelf (I've done this myself, but too much overhead for just passing a simple string along):

https://codeopinion.com/self-host-asp-net-web-api-as-a-windows-service/

Other options:

1. Communicate via TCP/IP directly
2. Use a database (server updates, VB6 reads)
3. use compicated system of arduino-activated relays to cause mice to take particular paths in a maze, and detect their movements (note: not entirely serious)
4. Lots of things I've not thought of